# How to make screenshots not "expire" on macOS?

Tags: macos

When I take a screenshot using cmd+shift+3 or cmd+shift+4, the screenshot becomes a draggable floating "virtual file" thing:

[image]

which then goes away after about 5 seconds and gets automatically saved to the desktop. Is there any way to have this virtual file stick around forever and not get automatically saved, or to extend its duration?

Comment: That’s not a virtual file. It’s more of a notification that allows you to quickly view the recent screen shot.  From that quick view you can launch the mark up tool.  Notifications and banners can’t hang around forever

Comment: You want it sitting in the bottom of your screen 'forever'? What would happen as you add more screenshots?